# DAG and Spark execution

Tags: apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to get a better understanding of the Spark internals and I am not sure how to interpret the resulting DAG of a job.
Inspired to the example described at http://dev.sortable.com/spark-repartition/,
I run the following code in the Spark shell to obtain the list of prime numbers from 2 to 2 million.

`val n = 2000000
val composite = sc.parallelize(2 to n, 8).map(x => (x, (2 to (n / x)))).flatMap(kv => kv._2.map(_ * kv._1))
val prime = sc.parallelize(2 to n, 8).subtract(composite)
prime.collect()`

After executing I checked the SparkUI and observed the DAG in figure.

Now my question is: I call the function subtract only once, why does this operation appears
three times in the DAG?
Also, is there any tutorial that explains a bit how Spark creates these DAGs?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subtract` is a transformation which requires a shuffle:

- First both `RDDs` have to be repartitioned using the same partitioner Local ("map-side") part of the transformation is marked as `subtract` in the stages 0 and 1. At this point both RDDs are converted to `(item, null)` pairs.
- `substract` you see in the stage 2 happens after the shuffle when RDDs have been combined. This where items are filtered.

In general any operation which requires a shuffle will be executed in at least two stages (depending on the number of predecessors) and tasks belonging to each stage will be shown separately.